# DocumentDB restore error unknown admin command atlasversion

Tags: mongodb, collections, mongodump, mongorestore, atlas

I have taken dump from atlas mongodb and facing an issue while restoring those data to AWS document DB.

```
mongorestore --ssl --host="<hostname>:27017" --username=<username> --password=<password> --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem /home/ubuntu/file
```

I am getting below error. How to overcome this issue?

> 2023-04-06T10:11:33.513+0000    WARNING: On some systems, a password provided directly using --password may be visible to system status programs such as `ps` that may be invoked by other users. Consider omitting the password to provide it via stdin, or using the --config option to specify a configuration file with the password.
>
> 2023-04-06T10:11:33.655+0000    Unknown admin command atlasVersion

Comment: Is this somehow different from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75955874/getting-error-in-mongodb-while-restoring-to-document-db-unknown-admin-command-a ?