# Getting Error In MongoDB While restoring to Document DB "Unknown admin command atlasVersion"

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas, mongorestore, mongodb-shell

I have taken the backup from Atlas mongodb,but the **Atlas account was suspended**. by using the backup i tried to restore it to aws documnentdb using the below command

```
mongorestore --ssl \
    --host="<hostname>:27017" \
    --username=<username> \
    --password=<password> \
    --sslCAFile rds-combined-ca-bundle.pem /home/ubuntu/file
```

Getting error for the above command: **Unknown admin command atlasVersion**

How can i restore it to aws documnentdb. Can someone help me to overcome the issue.

Comment: That seems like that version of mongorestore is not compatible with document db

Comment: I did this with a container from `mongo:4.0.28`.